# Error: invalid operands of types className<int>* and className<int>* to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make a class where I create a number based off of nodes linking to each other, allowing for larger integers. I overloaded the operator to allow individual nodes to add to each other as such:

```
template <class T>
class Number    {
public:
    Number(int bigNum = 0){
        value = bigNum;
    }
        Number operator + (Number const &num)   {
            Number* total = new Number(value + num.value);
            
            return *total;
        }
    T value;
    Number<T>* left;
    Number<T>* right;
};
//I'll just make the main function as follows:
int main() {

    Number<int> *num1 = new Number<int>(6);
    Number<int> *num2 = new Number<int>(4);
    Number<int> *total = num1 + num2;
}
```

I add two Numbers together here:

```
Number<T> *total = num1 + num2;
```

and got the following error:

> invalid operands of types `'Number<int>*'` and `'Number<int>*'` to
> binary 'operator+'

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `Number<T> *`'s?  You should just need `Number<T>` objects

Comment: Because each Number<T> connects to one another, so I need to use pointers to represent each one @NathanOliver

Comment: That seems like a flawed design.  If you need a list of numbers, you should be using a list class for that.  I number shouldn't need to know about other numbers.

Comment: You define an operator that adds 2 `Number<T>` objects but you try to use that for *pointers* (I think). Add more code or maybe it's just a typo?

Comment: That's just part of the assignment that I was told to do, was not by choice @NathanOliver

Comment: I tried adding * to them to make it take pointers as operands to no avail @AdrianMole

Comment: Remove all the `*` symbols and `new` keywords from your code, and it will work. (And change `T` to the correct type, or use `auto`)

Comment: Dereferencing the pointers, `Number<int> *total = *num1 + *num2;` exposes a different error, `Number operator + (Number const &num)` returns a `Number` rather than a `Number *`. It's a lot closer to what you want though, so I'd keep the change and start exploring the new error.

Comment: Mind you, that new error heads back to the problem Nathan Oliver pointed out earlier. You might want to stop coding for a while and try to clarify things with your instructor because you're walking into a rather large boobytrap.

Comment: @user4581301 This helped! I was able to fix my errors, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I suspect that you have merely solved the compiler error and will run smack-dab into logic errors when you come around to testing the program later (so test what you have very, very carefully now). You're going to find that, just like the languages used for human-human communication, it is very easy to write something that is that is syntactically correct--the grammar makes sense--but is logically flawed. The concept behind your code is broken, and this will make it difficult-to-impossible to create a properly functioning program.